# Get key in for each loop php

Tags: php

Hi i want to target a specific key in for each loop but there seems to be a problem in my code.

My array is like this. Now i only want to put apple in the select  tag. How do target it? Thanks

```html
Array
{
 [0] => fruit;
 [1] => apple;
 [2] => $3;
}
```

Here is my function

```html
function generateSelectFromArray($array){
      
    echo "<select>";
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        echo "<option value=' $key['1']'> $value </option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
```

Comment: Let me see if I understand your question. You are having trouble referring to `$key[index]` inside the string? Check how string interpolation works in PHP.

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? Create three duplicate options tag with the key and value of `1` and `apple`? Or create only one option tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function generateSelectFromArray($array){

    echo "<select>";
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == 'apple') {
            echo "<option value='$key'> $value </option>";
        }
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
```

Very simple, you just had to remove the ['1'], since the key is already bound to the variable, it's not an array.

Comment: Hi Djip, yes that will clear the error. But it will also echo all the value. I just want to target to echo the apple. Tnx